# Replace Method for multiple strings

Tags: replace

The data frame is about cars. So in seller columns have car company names and none(cars which selling by owner. So my aim is to change all company names to a simple string -'avtosalon'.

I've used for and replace method, code is running but, I can't get the result

```
for seller in data['Seller']:
    if seller== 'none':
        print('ok')
    else:
        seller=data['Seller'].replace('seller','avtosalon')
        print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

These are a few methods used to Replace Method for multiple strings

1. Use str. replace() to Replace Multiple Characters in Python.
2. Use re. sub() or re. subn() to Replace Multiple Characters in Python.
3. translate() and maketrans() to Replace Multiple Characters in Python.

refer here: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-replace-multiple-characters/